# Columnstore index creation fails with this error "There is insufficient memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query"

Tags: sql-server, indexing, columnstore

When trying to execute this command to create a columnstore index I get the following error  "There is insufficient memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query"

The server is SQL Server 2016 Enterprise. 5tb hard drive space, 128gb of RAM. Max memory is set to 120gb leaving 8gb for the OS. There are no other services aside from SQL running on this machine.

The table I am attempting to create the columnstore index on is 36gb, 2bn rows and 8 columns wide, predominantly int and date.

Am i correct in assuming that 120gb is insufficient? although i have tried running a columnstore on a 55m row 6gb table and that also failed.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [CCI-BIG] ON [DBO].[BIG_DATA]
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: You can try reducing the parallelism employed with `MAXDOP`; this has a big impact on how much memory is required. You can also tweak the amount of memory requested by changing the max memory grant setting in the resource pool -- see [this post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/the-case-of-the-columnstore-index-and-the-memory-grant/) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that you don't have enough RAM to create the index. You need to check the amount of RAM allocated to SQL Server (at least check the RAM utilization by SQL Server in Process Manager. It doesn't have to be less than the size of the table).

Also, try to reduce MAXDOP. For instance, run the following code:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [CCI-BIG] ON [DBO].[BIG_DATA]
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0, MAXDOP = 1) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```